# Job failed with state FAILED due to: Job commit failed: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2006 : Error adding partition to metastore

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

Using hive, sqoop, I can import data with instruction like this

```
sqoop import \
> --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.88.101:3306/test?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2 \
> --username root \
> --password 123456 \
> --table emp \
> --fields-terminated-by '\001' \
> --delete-target-dir \
> --target-dir '/sqoop/emp1' \
> --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

However, while using Sqoop to import data from local MYSQL especially with "--hcatalog-database ... --hcatalog-table ...", I always face problem like this:

```
2024-03-05 11:33:40,793 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2024-03-05 11:33:53,798 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1709541729536_0028 failed with state FAILED due to: Job commit failed: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2006 : Error adding partition to metastore. Cause : com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.registerPartitions(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:975)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.commitJob(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.handleJobCommit(CommitterEventHandler.java:286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.run(CommitterEventHandler.java:238)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4871)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.getOrCreate(HiveClientCache.java:292)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:267)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveMetastoreClient(HCatUtil.java:569)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.registerPartitions(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:777)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.utils.JavaUtils.newInstance(JavaUtils.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:133)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$5.call(HiveClientCache.java:297)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$5.call(HiveClientCache.java:292)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4876)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.utils.JavaUtils.newInstance(JavaUtils.java:84)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore.)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:169)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveClientCache.java:409)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore.)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:9085)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:9063)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:97)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:692)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:540)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
    ... 31 more
```

here is my big data tools version:

```
hive hive-3.1.3-bin
hadoop hadoop-3.3.4
sqoop sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0
```

I have add the homepath in profile, and copy the jar packages, which are  hive-hcatalog-core-3.1.3.jar and hive-hcatalog-server-extensions-3.1.3.jar ,from /hive/lib to /sqoop/lib